# Dúvida sobre atributos e métodos POO em PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando POO em PHP e me deparei com um exemplo que não entendi:

A parte do codigo que não entendi é porque o atributo `$produtos` esta sendo 
passado/chamando o metodo imprimir() em `$produto->imprimir()` e `tbm $usuario->imprimir();`

o exemplo é pra adicionar na variavel $r a saida desse dois trechos.

Como o atributo esta chamando o metodo e como funciona essa chamada?

segue o codígo:

```
<?php

class Compra {

    public $id, $produtos, $usuario;

    public function cadastrar(array $produtos, Usuario $usuario)
    {
        $this->id = rand(0, 1000);
        $this->produtos = $produtos;
        $this->usuario = $usuario;

    }

    public function imprimir()
    {
        $r = "Compra id" . $this->id . "<hr>";
        $r .= "Produtos" . "<br>"; #ESSA PARTE


        foreach ($this->produtos as $produto) {

            $r .= $produto->imprimir(); #ESSA PARTE

        }

        $r .= "<hr>";
        $r .= "Usuario" . $this->usuario->imprimir(); #ESSA PARTE

        return $r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, a class Compras espera um objeto da class Usuário, que deve ter um método imprimir, e uma coleção de objetos da classe Produto, que também deve ter um método imprimir.

```
<?php
class Produto
{
    public $id;

    public function imprimir()
    {
            $r = 'Eu sou o produto #' . $this->id;

            return $r;
    }
}

class Usuario
{
    public $id;

    public function imprimir()
    {
            $r = 'Eu sou o usuário #' . $this->id;

            return $r;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplesmente o "imprimir" da última parte que você mencionou, é um método de `Usuario`.

Note nessa linha:

```
public function cadastrar(array $produtos, Usuario $usuario)
                                           ^^^^^^^
```

O método "cadastrar" espera um **objeto** do tipo Usuário.

E ainda, dentro do método, este objeto é armazenado no membro da classe:

```
$this->usuario = $usuario;
```

O que você ficou em dúvida é mero desdobramento:

```
$r .= "Usuario" . $this->usuario->imprimir(); 
//                                   ^--- método do Usuario cadastrado
//                          ^--- objeto armazenado previamente no cadastrar
```

Aqui é chamado o método `imprimir();` da classe `Usuario`.

O fato de ter um método `imprimir()` em `Compra` é "praticamente" uma coincidência.

Seria o caso de você dar uma espiada na implementação da classe `Usuario` para conferir.

Tudo aqui se aplica para `Produtos` também, mas imagino que nessas alturas do campeonato vc já tenha entendido. Vale notar que apesar de `produtos` ser *array*, tudo indica que é um *array* de objetos do tipo `Produto`, que é desmembrado no `foreach`:

```
foreach ($this->produtos as $produto) {...
```

Comment: Clareou aqui pessoal, entendi. eu devo cirar uma classe Produto que implemente o metodo imprimir(); no caso faz parte do exercicio, agora que eu entendi o que deve ser feito. agradeço bastante!